# I want to Detect The changes in Contact made from anywhere programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, notifications, objective-c-blocks, addressbook

"   Hello Sir, I am working on an iOS application(client/server based) in which at a point after taking the permission from user i am accessing users contact list(AddressBook) to synch it with Server.Right now i am doing at ever time application lunch.But i want to synch my contact only when my app get a notification change in Users Contact List(AddressBook)  "

"After a lots of Searching i got that,ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback can help me ,but please someone tell me how i use it in my code,i mean the implementation of ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback in actual code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find my answer [here which worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440115/detect-what-was-changed-from-abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback/22292790#22292790). This may need some enhancements, but it works.

Comment: Sure the question is duplicate. :)

Comment: Bad answer this is just a comment and based on that comment you should have marked the question as a duplicate

Comment: Thanx A Lot Sir ,I have solved my problem with the help of your given Link.