# Update app core data/ Realm when user add new contact

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, contacts, realm

I'm currently working on an app, which take the all the address book contacts information and store it core data / Realm. But it happen only once, but how to capture when user add new contact / delete / update on the phone contact list.

Answer (score 0):

when user add or update the phonebook, you can capture the changes through external call back methods mentioned below.

IOS9

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(CNcontactDidChange:)name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

IOS8

```
 ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(book,MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback,(__bridge void *)(self));
```

Then use the method mentioned below to update Realm ,

```
+ (instancetype)createOrUpdateInRealm:(RLMRealm *)realm withValue:(id)value;
```

Comment: Yeah, but how to get the exact contact ID which changed the contact list ?

Comment: You don't get info about that, so that you need to refetch all contacts you are interested in.

Comment: Refer this link ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440115/detect-what-was-changed-from-abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback