# How to get changed contacts using Contacts Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, contacts

I can monitor contacts change using:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self, selector: #selector(contactStoreDidChange), name: .CNContactStoreDidChange, object: nil)
    }

@objc func contactStoreDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

}
```

But how can I get the changed contacts from the notification? Things like which contact is added/removed/changed etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can get notify in the method.and you have to then refetch all objects and create your dataSource again for updated data!!

Comment: If I have more than 1000 contacts and if i try to re-fetch all my contacts is slowing down my app. how to solve this issue??

Comment: You will have to perform this task in background without the attention of user, if you find some contacts updated then you can refresh UI , else its not even required, and user won't see any changes in performance.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440115/detect-what-was-changed-from-abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback