# Subscription to an event of Address Book in iOS

Tags: ios, publish-subscribe, addressbook

When a new contact is added to the address book, I need to do something to it. At least I need to get some contact identifiers for later use. As you may guess, I would like to my app works in background or maybe starts in the background when a new contact is added.

Is this even possible in iOS? If yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/1621989-abaddressbookregisterexternalcha?language=objc)
 Registers a callback to receive notifications when the Address Book database is modified.

You can get the updated contact with help of this : [Detect what was changed from ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440115/detect-what-was-changed-from-abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback)